# error when i am installing yolo on ubuntu 20

Tags: ubuntu, yolov4

when i run make command on darknet directory i get this error

./src/dark_cuda.c: In function ‘cuda_random’:
./src/dark_cuda.c:519:12: error: unknown type name ‘curandGenerator_t’

compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
make: *** [Makefile:177: obj/dark_cuda.o] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

Three things come to mind:

1. Don't build opencv yourself unless absolutely necessary.  It is a complex library, with many optional flags to pass in to get everything built correctly.  Instead, if you are on Ubuntu, you should be using a command such as `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev` to get OpenCV installed correctly.
2. What version of CUDA and CUDNN are you using?  Are you certain they are installed correctly and are recent?  Darknet requirements are listed here:  https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#requirements-for-windows-linux-and-macos
   Note that specific versions of CUDA and CUDNN are listed.
3. Lastly, see the FAQ which contains an entry for building on Linux:  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/darknet_faq/#how_to_build_on_linux as well as a link to my youtube video showing you step-by-step how to build it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJ2iyf_E9PM